# I have created new APP ID on facebook but I am not able to post the photos on facebook with old app id it is working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created new APP ID on facebook but I am not able to post the photos on facebook , but with other APP ID which I was created some months go I am able to post it
Why it is so?
Is there any permission required for APP ID?

```
- (void) startPosting {
spinnerView.labelText = @"Sharing";
[spinnerView startAnimating];

[self takeScreenshot];

FBRequest *request = [[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
               graphPath:@"me/albums"
               parameters:nil
               HTTPMethod:nil] autorelease];

FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[[FBRequestConnection alloc] init] autorelease];

//1 step - get all albums from user's profile
FBRequestHandler handler = ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog ( @"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [spinnerView stopAnimating];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSArray* albums = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

        NSString* path = @"me/photos";
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [albums count]; ++i)
        {
            NSDictionary* album = [albums objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString* albumType = [album objectForKey:@"type"];
            if ([albumType isEqualToString:@"wall"])
            {
                // publish the image onto the wall
                path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", [album objectForKey:@"id"]];
                break;
            }
        }

        [self postScreenshot:path];
    }
};
[newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];
[newConnection start];
}

- (void) postScreenshot:(NSString*)path {
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   screenShot, @"picture",
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out this %@ chart : %@", [SurveyManager appName],((UILabel*)self.navigationItem.titleView).text], @"message",
                   nil];

FBRequest *request = [[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
               graphPath:path
               parameters:parameters
               HTTPMethod:@"POST"] autorelease];

FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[[FBRequestConnection alloc] init] autorelease];

FBRequestHandler handler = ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    [spinnerView stopAnimating];
};
[newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];
[newConnection start];
```

}

Comment: can you post app settings page screenshot on the facebook.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/hmGVF53MMLWq this the setting page for my app

Comment: Make sure you have valid app id and app name(FacebookDisplayName, this should match the name in the facebook app settings.) entered in the ios app.

Comment: Actually I am able to login , authenticate but my photo is not uploading

Comment: Then show us your code that you are using to upload photo.

Comment: Please check this http://screencast.com/t/ybFgRTXdzbod I have uploaded photo 5 min ago from my app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39472/discussion-between-nishi-and-fahri-azimov)

Comment: Added my code for sharing the photo on fb

Comment: Just change the `picture` key to the `source`, and it should work. Good Luck!